# Export information about AWS volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ebs, jmespath

I want to export the list displayed in the Volume section of the EC2 Console into CSV (or at least text) and I am trying to use the CLI for that.

I have trouble getting the tags information right using [Filter Expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#filter-expressions):

```
me@home:/$ aws ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[*].Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value'
[
    [],
    [],
    [],
//...
    []
]
```

Here I expected to have a list with sometimes the value of the tag `Name` for the columes that have it and `[]` for those who don't.

Just to be sure, I checked and I do have Tags with that key (not always, though):

```
me@home:/$ aws ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[*].Tags[*].Key'
[
    [
        "kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/name",
        "Team",
        "env",
        "kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/namespace",
        "Name",
        "kubernetes.io/cluster/DW",
        "Software",
        "Env",
        "kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name"
    ],
    [
        "env",
        "Software",
        "eks:nodegroup-name",
        "Team",
        "eks:cluster-name"
    ],
    [
        "Name",
        "Software",
        "Team",
        "kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/name",
        "kubernetes.io/cluster/DW",
        "kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name",
        "env",
        "Env",
        "kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/namespace"
    ],
//...
]
```

So, how can I get that information right ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing is that you are breaking the shell quotes with the ones inside your JMESPath expression.

You should be using a [literal expression](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#literal-expressions), instead

```sh
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[*].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value'
```

or using double quotes for the shell `query` option value

```sh
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[*].Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value"
```